# symfony2 find field in form errors

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a complicated form which has lots of fields in it and it was created by an other developer. Now when I submit the form I get the very common error

> This value should not be blank.

I need to find out what is the value. I know about Entities mapping and "nullable=false" property, what I actually need is, the best practice/technique or just a solution, to find out what is this value that is missing. It is a complicated Form and if there is a different path to take rather than go through entity and all subfields that are added to it, I would really appreciate it.

I am pretty sure Symfony devs would have considered that and I need to find how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this for debugging purpose, you could do something like:

```
{{ dump(form.getErrors(TRUE,TRUE)) }}
```

As for the production, you need to put appropriate validation constraint's messages. For example, using annotaions:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;

/**
 * @NotBlank(message="Title should not be empty")
 */
private $title;
```

After that, error should display the message above instead of generic one.

Answer (score 0):

- There may be `new NotBlank()` attached to form field in formtype
  class.
- There may be `@Assert\NotBlank` attached to field property in entity
  class.
- There may be `@Assert\NotBlank` attached to field property in model
  class.

So if you set update them as below, you'll know what field it is.

```
new NotBlank('message' => 'Code is required.')
@Assert\NotBlank(message="Code is required.")
```

Or just work with Form error handling class.